# Does OpenL2tp can through NAT?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, nat

I install openl2tp(http://www.openl2tp.org/) in my server, lan ip of the

server is 192.168.1.100  and wan ip of the server is 82.103.143.89. i can connect l2tp

server in local area network， but i can not connect the l2tp server with wan ip, who could tell

me the reason ? thanks!

-----------BTW-------------

1 I can not connect to WAN from both inside or the outside of the network;

2 the routing is ok and the 1701 port is open

3 there are not enough error logs except some retry messages :(

Comment: hw did you manage to install openl2tp im trying to install it and getting errors can u plz have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576087/openl2tp-make-on-centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify if you are connecting to WAN from inside or from the outside of the network; but regardless I can actually only offer general troubleshooting instructions>

You should can start checking the connection by

- pinging the IP, to prove routing is ok
- scanning if the specific port is open, to check firewall configuration (in this case UDP 1701)
- finally connecting with the actual client and examining logs (if possible tell the client to be verbose)

Once you have these results include the finding in the question itself